# Convert Table Creation from DAX to M code for Dynamic Measure/Column table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I've successfully implemented a table that allows me to dynamically change the columns within a visual using a slicer. The table is created using the following DAX code, and works as expected:

```
ChartType Slicer = 
VAR Stage = ADDCOLUMNS( VALUES( factOpportunityProduct[StageName (Short)] ), "Dimension" , "Stage")
VAR AgeStatus = ADDCOLUMNS( VALUES( factOpportunityProduct[Opportunity Age Status] ), "Dimension" , "Age Status") 
VAR RVP_PTP = ADDCOLUMNS( VALUES( factOpportunityProduct[RVPPTPPriority__c] ), "Dimension" , "RVP PTP Priority") 
RETURN UNION(Stage , AgeStatus, RVP_PTP)
```

Which returns this table:

| Value | Dimension |
| --- | --- |
| Stage 1 | Stage |
| Stage 2 | Stage |
| Aged | Age Status |
| Non Aged | Age Status |
| A | Priority |
| B | Priority |

The gotchya is that this new table doesn't adhere to the SortOrder Column I've set up for Stage, and when creating a new conditional column on the table outside of PQ, there is a circular reference error. To overcome this, I decided I could just create the table in M.

Here's the code I've written so far, however the format isn't correct and I feel that there may be an easier way:

```
= let
Source = Table.Distinct( Table.FromColumns( {factOpportunityProduct[Opportunity Age Status]} ))
in
    Source
```

My next solution attempt would be to create 3 separate tables for each column and create a new query that appends these 3 tables together, then disable load on those 3 separate tables.

Any help would be appreciated!